# Inheritance in CSS properties?

Tags: css

Sorry, but no matter how often I read it, I just don't grok it.

I have declared

```
.submit_button  
{  
  font: 12px Arial;  
  margin:0px;  
  padding:2px;  
}
```

and now I want to declare `centered_submit_button` which inherits from `submit_button` and adds `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`

Please take pity on me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, vanilla CSS doesn't have any notion of inheritance, but you can achieve what you need with this:

```
.submit_button, .centered_submit_button
{
    font: 12px Arial;  
    margin: 0px;  
    padding: 2px; 
}

.centered_submit_button
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This is probably all that you need, but as [scurker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139054/scurker) mentioned, there are CSS-enhancing tools such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) that provide inheritance-like constructs as well as many other nice features that can improve your quality-of-life as a web developer.

In this case, LESS is ironically more verbose, but arguably more expressive:

```
.button ()
{
    font: 12px Arial;
    margin: 0px;  
    padding: 2px; 
}

.submit_button
{
    .button;
}

.centered_submit_button
{
    .button;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Another similar tool is [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/), which does most of what LESS does, but also has a very indifferent attitude about using punctuation in your syntax:

```
button()
    font 12px Arial
    margin 0px
    padding 2px

.submit_button
    button

.centered_submit_button
    button
    margin-left auto
    margin-right auto
```

Both LESS and Stylus have client-side JavaScript implementations, so you have the option to host your `.less` or `.stylus` files directly or to compile them on the server and host the resulting CSS.

Comment: You missed the . in the first instance of centered_submit_button.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work quite like that. There is no concept of inheritance in that sense, in CSS. However, what you CAN do, is define the common attributes of `.submit_button` and `.centered_submit_button`, and then redefine the things you want to do differently, for only `.centered_submit_button`, like this:

```
.submit_button, .centered_submit_button
{  
  font: 12px Arial;  
  margin:0px;  
  padding:2px;  
}

.centered_submit_button
{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately CSS inheritance doesn't work that way. If you want to do something like you're asking, you'll need to use something like [Less](http://lesscss.org). Otherwise you'll have to define the properties per element or add multiple classes to an element.

Comment: +1 because Less is awesome, and I was *just* about to edit my response to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's up with these people who say you "can't do inheritance" in CSS. Sure, CSS doesn't call it inheritance, but you can still accomplish the same effect. It all hinges on a topic called [CSS specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), which says that when there is a conflict of rules, the most specific rule will be applied.

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
.submit_button  
{  
  font: 12px Arial;  
  margin:0px;  
  padding:2px;  
}

.submit_button.centered
{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The first rule given defines the styling for all elements with class `submit_button`. The second rule applies to all elements with class `submit_button` and class `centered`. It's perfectly valid HTML and CSS to have multiple classes on a single element (just separate the class names with spaces in the HTML `class` attribute). Now, the second rule is more specific than the first, since it matches everything the first rule does (`submit_button` class) plus something more (`centered` class). As a result, the conflict in the `margin` rule for the `centered` class is resolved by taking `0 auto` over `0`.

Specificity is very powerful once you are familiar with how it works. It really helps reduce code in situations like the one you just described.

Comment: Specificity is certainly important to know about, but I don't think it's very similar to inheritance. In your example you have to apply 2 classes to your element, and it's possible that .centered has other rules as well. Conceptually speaking, I don't think this is more like inheritance than the other method people posted, but it is interesting to note anyway.